# Itextpdf resultset in each column of a three columned table

Tags: java, itext

I have a table:

> customer
>   
> John
>   
> Mike
>   
> Jenny
>   
> Fe
>   
> Susan

Now I want them to be generated using `itextpdf` that will look like this:

> |John    |Mike   |Jenny|
>   
>   |           Fe    | Susan

and so on.

How to do this using `java` and `itextpdf`?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the code you have so far. That way we can also see if you're using iText 5 or iText 7 (there's a huge difference).

Comment: *"that will look like this"* - How is that output format defined? The first row seems to point towards 3 table columns, the second to 2 columns, and the column division seems to independent in both rows. In other words, you seem to want the result to look as chaotic as possible.